# select * from table where id=1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I need to return all information from the row with the ID 1

the name of Table is customer
and the column is DescricaoID

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id=1";
                $query = mysql_query($sql);
                while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $id = $sql["1"];
                echo "Resultados para o ID $id";
                }
```

The output must be:

The customer **with id 1** is: **Jessica**

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $id = $sql["1"];
```

do this:

```
$id = $sql['id'];
```

(i don't know why you put a 1 there...)

Comment: yes, these are already collected in your query ("WHERE id=1")
if you want to echo out other information, you have to use for exampe:
$name = $sql['name'];
$date =  $sql['date']; and so on.
maybe i still don't understand your question